# Deep clone (with material) no longer works with v0.91

Tags: three.js

I use the version 0.79. To clone some meshes, i use these prototypes:

```
// Prototypes
THREE.Object3D.prototype.GdeepCloneMaterials = function() 
{

                var object = this.clone( new THREE.Object3D(), false );
                for ( var i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++ ) 
                {
                        var child = this.children[ i ];
                        if ( child.GdeepCloneMaterials ) 
                        {
                                object.add( child.GdeepCloneMaterials() );
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                                object.add( child.clone() );
                        }
                }
                return object;
};

THREE.Mesh.prototype.GdeepCloneMaterials = function( object, recursive ) 
{
        if ( object === undefined ) {
                object = new THREE.Mesh( this.geometry, this.material.clone() );
        }
        THREE.Object3D.prototype.GdeepCloneMaterials.call( this, object, recursive );
        return object;
};
/////////////

loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
loader.load( '/public/scene/Spawn.dae', function(geometry) 
{
        clone=geometry.scene.GdeepCloneMaterials();
});
```

I want to update to the version 0.91 but the deep clone method no longer works and i get error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: this.material.clone is not a function
at Mesh.THREE.Mesh.GdeepCloneMaterials at Group.THREE.Object3D.GdeepCloneMaterials
```

How to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: What is the full call stack for the error? [`Material.clone`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/Material.clone) has _not_ been deprecated.

Comment: A reasonable guess is `material` in your case is an array of materials.

Comment: @WestLangley As much as I like the simplicity of dealing with a raw array of materials, situations like this definitely make a case _for_ the old `THREE.MultiMaterial` object... Much easier to do `var newMat = mat.clone();` than `var newMat = Array.isArray(mat)? mat.reduce(function(acc, m){ acc.push(m.clone()); }, []) : mat.clone();`

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Indeed, now it's  array of materials. So I applied the patch. It works but my meshs are still not like before. I will look at the side of the colladaloader, there must have been changes since.